# CW structure of $S^2$ with two poles identified

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition, fundamental-groups, cw-complexes

I am trying to find a CW complex structure for $S^2$ with two poles identified. I would then use this to find its fundamental group, as in Hatcher 1.2.7.
To solve this, I first tried to construct $S^1$ with two points identified. Here is my construction:

- Take two 0-cells, x and y
- Take three 1-cells, e.g. ]0, 1[, ]2, 3[ and ]4, 5[, and use attaching maps that identify 0 and y and 5 together, and 1 & x & 2 as well as 3 & x & 4 together.
  This gives the following diagram:[Diagram for $S^1$ with poles identified][1]

I think this gives what I want. I then attach two 2-cells to this circle to give the left and right hemispheres of a 2-sphere with 2 poles identified.

My questions:

- In all other questions on this topic, this is not the construction given. Is something wrong with my construction? Perhaps my attaching maps are not continuous, but I can't see why...
- Can I think of $S^1$ with two points identified as $S^1 \vee S^1$, i.e. a figure of eight? Intuitively, if I glue the two points together literally (thinking of the construction as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$) then I get a figure of eight. Are they homotopy-equivalent?
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocry3.jpg

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: nowhere do I see two poles being identified

Comment: If you agree that my 1-skeleton is $S^1$ with two points identified, then doesn't attaching two 2-cells to the 1-skeleton make two hemispheres, still with the two points identified?

Comment: To answer your second question: yes, $S^1$ with two points identified is in fact homeomorphic to $S^1 \vee S^1$.

Comment: In the title you write $S^1$, in the text $S^2$. I therefore vote to close your question. Please make an edit to clarify this.

Comment: @PaulFrost done.

Comment: Close vote retracted!